# Connecting Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I am not able to connect to my Oracle database Its giving me error:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>          java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>          ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

What setting I need?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is cause by an issue in your Java runtime environment. There are two ways to fix it:

1) Upgrade to the latest version of Java from here: [**Latest Java**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

2) Run the `timezone updater tool` which fixes the issue in older versions: [**Timezone Updater Tool**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)